# pub.dev Firebase Messaging example Undefined class 'MessageArguments' eror

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

The *pub.dev* Firebase Messaging example located at the link below fails to compile in the Flutter/Android Studio with the following error:

```
Undefined class 'MessageArguments'.
```

[image: screen]

The source code and libraries are here:
[https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example][2]

Has anyone successfully compiled this example, and/or do you have suggestions how to resolve this error?

Comment: Did you import the required library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this and it is from [message.dart](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/message.dart)

```dart
/// Message route arguments.
class MessageArguments {
  /// The RemoteMessage
  final RemoteMessage message;

  /// Whether this message caused the application to open.
  final bool openedApplication;

  // ignore: public_member_api_docs
  MessageArguments(this.message, this.openedApplication);
}
```

Also It is better to accept null from route.

```dart
final MessageArguments? args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
```

Do a null check when using this args.

Comment: Nice tip, Yeasin. I'm wondering why my copy of message.dart does not have this class definition? Inserting your code into the copy of message.dart that I downloaded from the example resolves the error, but new ones pop up regarding message_list. In any case, how does one download the entire project from Git? I see no button that says 'download' or 'clone' so I have been manually copying and pasting the code. Thoughts?

Comment: I think example doesn't comes with installing package. You generally dont have to download/clone unless you like to make changes on package. just include on pinspec.yaml and it will good to go